# window.location.href does not work

Tags: javascript

I have the below java script function in which I want to redirect the page to another page. I verified that 'Got' message is shown by the alert function. So, the function is invoked properly. However, the page redirection with window.location.href does not work. Moreover, the alert function that prints the content of option, vDaeId, dgpId does not executed (I dont see a pop up in the browser). Could you please tell me what's wrong with this piece of code? Thanks. I am using firefox btw.

```
        function goToPMDisplayer(){
            alert('Got '); 
            var option=document.getElementById("D1").value;
            var vDaeId=document.getElementById("D2").value;
            var dgpId=document.getElementById("dgpids").value;
            var str= option + " "+ vDaeId + " "+ dgpId
            alert(str); 
            window.location.href="display.jsp?option="+option + "&vdaeid=" + vDaeId + "&dgpid=" + dgpId

        }
```

Comment: are there missing ";"s ?

Comment: @Sebas - Not a problem in Javascript.

Comment: If the `alert(str)` doesn't work, that means there's an error on one of your `var` lines`.  My guess is one of those elements don't exist.

Comment: I just added semi colonns. No change. Any other suggestion?

Comment: try putting this script just before `</body>`. That should make sure the elements exist before execution.

Comment: @Joseph: Or `window.onload = function(){ // your code }`

Comment: I verified that all ements exist.

Comment: @Fardaarda: Where is this code ran?  It might run before the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Fardaarda: *"I verified that all ements exist."* Can you post a complete test case in the question, then? (And ideally *also* to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net) I'm not immediately seeing why the code would fail if those elements really exist and really have those `id` values. I suspect an error in the definition of the elements that you're not seeing.

Comment: @Fardaarda: I've done a complete example in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10620371/157247). Works fine, provided the elements exist and really have those `id` values. Due respect, I think they must not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Moreover, the alert function that prints the content of option, vDaeId, dgpId does not executed (I dont see a pop up in the browser).

That tells us that the code is failing by throwing an exception. My guess would be that you don't have at least one of the elements you're relying on having (`D1`, `D2`, or `dgpids`). So `document.getElementById` returns `null`, and when you try to access `.value` on it, you get an exception.

Note that the strings you use with `getElementById` must be **`id`** values, not `name`s. So you must have `id="D1"` on one element, `id="D2"` on another, and `id="dgpids"` on another. Also note that `id` values can be case-sensitive, and that they **must** be unique on the page. (Most browsers will give you the first one in document order if you mess up that last rule, but...)

I assume that you're not calling `goToPMDisplayer` until the page is fully loaded, but if you're calling it during page load, make sure you're not calling it until after the elements exist (e.g., put the call to it lower in the document than the elements).

---

For problems like this, `alert`-style debugging went out some years ago. Here in 2012, we use proper debuggers. There's one built into all major browsers these days, even IE. You can set break points, walk through code, inspect the current state of the DOM... In short, no need to fumble about in the dark; you can shine light on what's happening.

---

In a comment on the question, you've said

> I verified that all ements exist.

With all due respect, I just don't see how that can be. I suspect the `id` values are slightly different, or that they don't have `id` values at all, but rather they have `name` values.

Here's a complete, working example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ujeguy) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ujeguy/edit#html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="D1" value="valueOfD1">
  <input id="D2" value="valueOfD2">
  <input id="dgpids" value="valueOfdgpids">
  <br><input id="theButton" type="button" value="Click Me">
  <script>
  function goToPMDisplayer(){
      alert('Got '); 
      var option=document.getElementById("D1").value;
      var vDaeId=document.getElementById("D2").value;
      var dgpId=document.getElementById("dgpids").value;
      var str= option + " "+ vDaeId + " "+ dgpId
      alert(str); 
      var loc = "display.jsp?option="+option + "&vdaeid=" + vDaeId + "&dgpid=" + dgpId
      alert("loc = " + loc);

  }
  document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = goToPMDisplayer;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you are right there were name tags but not id tags. I placed the id tags as well but the problem is still there. Can there be st else I am missing? Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Fardaarda: If you've added `id` values and you're still seeing the problem, you'll have to post the code (**only** the minimum needed for a self-contained test case, such as mine above).

Comment: I am sorry I noticed I made another syntactical mistake. Seeting idS helped and now I can see all three variables in the pop up window opened by alert but the page still is not redirected. What can be wrong?

Comment: @Fardaarda: I don't know, it looks fine to me. I usually would just assign to `window.location` rather than `window.location.href`, so you might try that, but either should work.

Comment: I tried window.location as well. The browser still does not go to display.jsp. Thanks a lot anyway for your help and the explanation.

Comment: I just tried window.open and it worked fine. I dont know what's wrong with window.location.

Answer (score 5):

You said the first alert works, and the second doesn't, that means one of these lines has a javascript error:

```
var option=document.getElementById("D1").value;
var vDaeId=document.getElementById("D2").value;
var dgpId=document.getElementById("dgpids").value;
```

The most likely culprit is that one of these elements does not exist, and attempting to access `.value` of `null` will throw an exception.